# How to fetch coordinates of Polygon in React.JS using react-google-maps

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, react-google-maps

I wants to fetch all the coordinates of a polygon drawn on Google's Map. And here is my code

```
import React from "react";
import { compose, withProps } from "recompose";
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker
} from "react-google-maps";
//import withScriptjs from "react-google-maps/lib/async/withScriptjs";
import { DrawingManager } from "react-google-maps/lib/components/drawing/DrawingManager";

const MyMapComponent = compose(
  withProps({
    /**
     * Note: create and replace your own key in the Google console.
     * https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard
     * The key "AIzaSyBkNaAGLEVq0YLQMi-PYEMabFeREadYe1Q" can be ONLY used in this sandbox (no forked).
     */
    googleMapURL:
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyALpmb4KhFoR2Kcvty21gzzegprl4ilIgs&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props => (
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={8}
    defaultCenter={new window.google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)}
  >
    <DrawingManager
      defaultDrawingMode={
        window.google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.ControlPosition
      }
      defaultOptions={{
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
          position: window.google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
          drawingModes: [
            window.google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
            window.google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
            window.google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
            window.google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
          ]
        },
        circleOptions: {
          fillColor: `#ffff00`,
          fillOpacity: 1,
          strokeWeight: 5,
          clickable: false,
          editable: true,
          zIndex: 1
        }
      }}
    />
    {props.isMarkerShown && (
      <Marker position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }} />
    )}
  </GoogleMap>
));
```

My focus of work is to fetch all the coordinates of that polygon that should be drawn on Google Maps.I also wants to store these coordinates in MongoDB using mongoose and NodeJs as backend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use this function to get all the coordinates of a polygon or any other reactangle.

```
function getPaths(polygon) {

  var polygonBounds = polygon.getPath();
  var bounds = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < polygonBounds.length; i++) {
    var point = {
      lat: polygonBounds.getAt(i).lat(),
      lng: polygonBounds.getAt(i).lng()
    };
    bounds.push(point);
  }
  console.log(bounds);
}
```

And in GoogleMap component, i simplified the above code by given way.

```
<DrawingManager
    drawingMode={"polygon"}
    onPolygonComplete={value => console.log(getPaths(value))} />
```